How to automatically create a user in django
I'm trying to create an application form so that people who would like to work for us can apply to our organization. I had a conversation with my client and he doesn't want new employees to create their own user login info. Instead, he wants me to create an admin page where he'll accept or decline applicants. If he accepts an applicant, it'll automatically create user login info, and email that applicant their login info. The user will of course be able to change their login info once they enter their account. How can this be done?
I tried to create a signup sheet, but that ended up creating a user before the admin accepted the applicant.
User = get_user_model()
class InterpreterCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    ssn = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=False)
    languages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_interpreter = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
            interpreter = Interpreter(
                user=user,
                address=self.cleaned_data['address'],
                phone_number=self.cleaned_data['phone_number'],
            )
            interpreter.save()
            interpreter.languages.set(self.cleaned_data['languages'])
        return user


This can be done in a number of ways.. the simple one is.

Create user with django.contrib.auth.models User Model,
set User.password = default_password User.groups= default_password.
Set User.is_active = false, user.groups.add(name='groupname') then User.save() it
In Admin panel list all in_active Employee/User
define function def activate_employee to active applicant\Employee from Admin panel  i.e. accepts an applicant, then create user login info, and email that applicant their login info.

if you want add extra field to User, create UserProfie/Interpreter model and define OneToOne relation with django.contrib.auth User Model
model.py
class Interpreter(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(verbose_name="phone number", max_length=10)
    birthdate = models.DateField(verbose_name="birth date")
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=2, max_length=10)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # address = models.ForeignKey(to=Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'interpreter'

Now import both model to from.py django.contrib.auth User Model and Interpreter model in Form,
In your forms.py
class InterpreterCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    ssn = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=False)
    languages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_interpreter = True
        if commit:
            user.is_inactive= False
        # Generate password for user
            user.password = 'default_password'
        # you can crate a group for new employees
            user.group.add('new_employees') 
        # then save user  
            user.save()
        # user we just save is inactive user with default_password, which will not able to login. 
            interpreter = Interpreter(
                user=user,
                address=self.cleaned_data['address'],
                phone_number=self.cleaned_data['phone_number'],
            )
           interpreter.save()
           interpreter.languages.set(self.cleaned_data['languages'])
         return user
    

make sure you set 'is_active= False' while creating new user.
this will not allow user to login.

another way is you can define User Model which save required field to create account. list them to Admin panel. when admin approve applicant, create User with  'django.contrib.auth.models User Model and  email that applicant their login info.

you are working on the User Model, so a User is created if you save. I don't think there is much to do about it.
I would create my own Model which mimics the Usermodel. This Model would have two functions: Delete and ConvertToUser.
You would need two create a seperate View to wire up the functions.
